# Insert comma on new line in array

Tags: insert-mode, formatting

I like to format my arrays like this:

```
myArray = [ "lorem"
          , "ipsum"
          , "dolor"
          , "sit"
          , "amet"
          ];
```

If I open a new line below the "amet" line, I would like vim to automatically insert a comma so that I end up with:

```
myArray = [ "lorem"
          , "ipsum"
          , "dolor"
          , "sit"
          , "amet"
          , 
          ];
```

Similar to how vim automatically insert comments with `set formatoptions=ro`

Comment: 1) Your question is not a question. It is not clear what you are asking.
2) The syntax for how you format arrays is strange, to say the least. Commas should follow the word without whitespace, i.e. `"lorem", ...`. Of course, you're free to do as you like, but you should consider to follow more standard conventions, as that is better wrt. collaboration.

Comment: You could map `o` and `O` for that filetype to consider context and do the right thing (e.g. via an `<expr>` mapping), but I imagine it will be troublesome

Answer (score 1):

This works by checking if there is an opening and closing bracket inside the result of a `yip`. `O` does nothing if used at the top of the document.

```
function! CommaInList (eol)
  " enforce eol?
  let curLine = getline ('.')
  let curPos  = getpos  ('.')
  if a:eol && (curPos[2] < len(curLine))
    norm! a^M
    return
  endif

  " current line must contain , or [
  if (match(curLine, '^ *,[^,]*$') != 0) && (match(curLine, '\[[^\],]*$') == -1)
    norm! o
    return
  endif

  " Cursor must be inside an array
  norm! m""ayip'"
  if match(@a, '[^\[\]]*\[[^,\n]*\n[^\]]*\]') != 0
    norm! o
    return
  endif

  " Comma!
  let line = repeat(' ', match (curLine, '[,\[][^,\[]*$')).", "
  exec ('norm! "="'.line.'\n"^Mp$')
endfunction

nmap <silent>o :call CommaInList(0)<cr>a
nmap <silent>O k:call CommaInList(0)<cr>a
imap <silent><cr> <esc>:call CommaInList(1)<cr>a
```